# Facebook non friend cannot like public post from ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

```
[Facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"1000029327084_2428832476/likes" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];
```

This is what I do for posting my like to Facebook. This works fine only for friends even if the post is public. That is non friends cannot like any posts and got an error 210:

```
{
   "error": {
"message": "(#210) User not visible", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 210
}
}
```

any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's almost certainly the user's privacy settings - mine are set such that even on Public posts, only friends-of-friends can interact with them - what did the Post's details say about your ability to like or comment on the post? IIRC there's a boolean value returned

Comment: Thanks for you replay. When using the Graph API Explorer a true value or an error is returned. But in my app there is no response. I put breakpoints in both request: didReceiveResponse and request: didLoad but in both cases(success or error) there is no response.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your app has any user restrictions set in the App Dashboard. Ensure the user-ids are not subject to the restrictions you have set.

Check if FB has placed any restrictions on your app (eg. Mobile Web integration is blocked by FB).  If so, resolve them.

Set the "iPhone App Store ID" in the App Dashboard.  You can enter a fake one like 123456, for testing/development.